# Using Google Maps API to find routes & distance between two locations and present it in a table

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to use Google maps to find out available routes between two cities. Some information about these routes like distance and travel time etc.

I **do not** want this data to be presented in a Map. I need this to be presented to end user in textual format.

User will give me two cities and I will present him with various routes and **information in a table.**

Can this be done using PHP, MySQL and Google Maps? Any pointers would be very helpful.

Comment: You should read the Terms of Service because if you use the directions API then the results must be shown in connection with a Map

Answer (score 4):

If you want multiple routes between two points, use the directions service (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions) and specify `alternatives=true` in the request. This will return alternate routes, if they're available. Then, parse the response for the desired information:

- there will be one `legs` array for each route
- within that `legs` array, there is a `distance` and a `duration` field, each containing a raw value and a textual value.

If you don't need multiple choices for the route, the Google Maps Distance Matrix service (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) provides travel distance and time between multiple origins and destinations, without all of the directions information.

A sample table is in the blog post: http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/05/what-is-distance-matrix.html

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps Direction Service can give you textual information.  See the documentation here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Directions
Particularly the bit starting *"A DirectionsRenderer not only handles display of the polyline and any associated markers, but also can handle the textual display of directions as a series of steps. To do so, simply call setPanel() on your DirectionsRenderer, passing it the  in which to display this information."*

Comment: I am not talking about textual directions alone. I just need map info in text format instead of a graphical map.

Comment: Maybe you should use the Directions API instead of Google Maps then: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/